# Trying to insert multiple data into one row, but get multiple rows instead

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm trying to do a many-many database select, where I have *events* and *music styles* (among others). However since one event can have multiple music styles I decided to do a many-many relationship model.

This is what I created:

```
SELECT 
     a.* FROM music_types AS a, events_music_types AS b 
WHERE 
     a.id = b.music_type_id 
AND 
     b.event_id = events.ID
```

And inserted it into my code which now looks like this:

```
$query =    
"SELECT
    events.EVENT_NAME, events.start_datetime, events.end_datetime, events.VENUE_LOCATION, events.PARTY_TYPE, events.IMAGE_URL, events.ENTRANCE_PRICE, 
    venues.VENUE_NAME, venues.BEER_PRICE, venues.WINE_PRICE, SPIRITS_PRICE, 
    party_types.PARTYTYPE, 
    a.*
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues 
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
INNER JOIN party_types
    ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
INNER JOIN music_styles AS a, events_music_styles AS b
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
AND a.id = b.music_style_id 
AND b.event_id = events.ID
";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th> Poster </th>
<th> Event Name </th>
<th> Venue Name </th>
<th> Party Type </th>
<th> Entrance Price </th>
<th> Music </th>
<th> € of Beer </th>
<th> € of Wine </th>
<th> € of Spirits </th>
</tr>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><IMG src='" . $row['IMAGE_URL'] . "'></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['EVENT_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['VENUE_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['PARTYTYPE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ENTRANCE_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['MUSIC_STYLE_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['BEER_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['WINE_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['SPIRITS_PRICE'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

However, while the code does get all of the music styles for an event, it doesn't put it into one row but duplicates the row the amount of times that there are musical styles for each event.

[image]

How would I go about combining it into one row and separating the music styles with a comma? Thanks :)!

Comment: If you tell us what you want to get as a result in that column, we can determine how to get it.

Comment: The result is so that the rows don't split when there's multiple music styles. In this case, there should only be one row with the Music Column being "Partymix, rap".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to -

```
$query =    
"SELECT
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    events.start_datetime,
    events.end_datetime,
    events.VENUE_LOCATION,
    events.PARTY_TYPE,
    events.IMAGE_URL,
    events.ENTRANCE_PRICE, 
    venues.VENUE_NAME,
    venues.BEER_PRICE,
    venues.WINE_PRICE,
    SPIRITS_PRICE, 
    party_types.PARTYTYPE,
    GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues 
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
INNER JOIN party_types
    ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
INNER JOIN events_music_styles
    ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id
INNER JOIN music_styles
    ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
GROUP BY events.ID
";
```

You also had a mix of join styles before which I have now corrected.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT`? That's what I was missing! +1

Comment: Thanks nnichols! I however ran into an error `Unknown column 'music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME' in 'field list'` even after adding `music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME` to my select area.

Comment: Did you copy the entire query across? I have changed the joins.

Comment: Yup, I copied the entire thing.

Comment: And if I were to keep the old syntax and include your `group_concat` to it, would that theoretically work?

Comment: It would but please don't. Mixed styles like that are horrible. It was a small error. I forgot to remove the table alias after `INNER JOIN music_styles`. If you remove the `AS a` it should work fine.

Comment: Haha, okay. Thank you for all your help nnichols! I am forever grateful for your work. I also thank Rick for his thoughtful answer as well :)

Comment: Glad it's all working now. Just a final quick note - using the `JOIN ... ON` syntax is so much easier to read and it puts all the join criteria next to the table names instead of clogging up the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

With appropriate `GROUP BY` statements in the query and use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Hey glglgl, by inserting `GROUP BY events.ID` at the end, all I achieve is that the other duplicate rows disappear, but all of the `music_styles` data isn't combined into the one row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any mysql functions that can accomplish that directly. Perhaps someone can correct me on that. You can look into `CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION`, but the documentation seems pretty confusing at first glance.

The other alternative is grouping them in PHP. First, you'd want to add `events.ID as eventID` and `venues.ID as venueID` to your `SELECT` list. Then in your `while` loop, you'd want to group them as associative arrays, and add a new value to each `$row` to concatenate the music styles. After that loop, you'd then want to loop through your new array of data, and output the values you've gained. The ones that were the same will have overwritten, and you'll have your new, concatenated string to call on.

Creating an aggregate function in mysql would likely be faster and more efficient though. You'd want to create one that takes in all the values, concatenates them, and returns the string. In your `SELECT` it would work similarly to using a `SUM()` or other built-in aggregate.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I will try searching around for that and see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: @Rick - you described the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function :) See my answer below.

Comment: @nnichols Already +1'd you for it, lol. I was hoping something like that would exist, but didn't know where to start looking.

Comment: Cheers @Rick. It is a really handy function but sadly not standard. I do not think any other RDBMS has a native implementation of it.